# PyQt5: Create semi-transparent window with non-transparent children

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I want to create a fullscreen window with semitransparent background, but fully visible children widgets (kind of overlay effect).

Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create the main window
window = QMainWindow()

window.setWindowOpacity(0.3)
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
window.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

# Create the button
pushButton = QPushButton(window)
pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(240, 190, 90, 31))
pushButton.setText("Finished")
pushButton.clicked.connect(app.quit)

# Center the button
qr = pushButton.frameGeometry()
cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
qr.moveCenter(cp)
pushButton.move(qr.topLeft())

# Run the application
window.showFullScreen()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This creates a semi-transparent effect, but even the button is semi-transparent.

I also tried to substitute the

```
window.setWindowOpacity(0.3)
```

with this call

```
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

but to no avail, in this case the background was *fully transparent* (while the button was correctly fully visible).

**Solution: (implemented thanks to Aaron's suggestion)**:

The trick is in implementing a custom paintEvent for the main window.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomWindow(QMainWindow):
    def paintEvent(self, event=None):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setOpacity(0.7)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white))   
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create the main window
window = CustomWindow()

window.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

# Create the button
pushButton = QPushButton(window)
pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(240, 190, 90, 31))
pushButton.setText("Finished")
pushButton.clicked.connect(app.quit)

# Center the button
qr = pushButton.frameGeometry()
cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
qr.moveCenter(cp)
pushButton.move(qr.topLeft())

# Run the application
window.showFullScreen()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ```window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)```  both are not required

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, while is seems not to work with the available flags you can still use `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` because it is possible to draw a semitranparent rect on that transparency.

Derive your mainwindow from QMainWindow and use that class instead.

Apply `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)` to that class

Implement the paintEvent of your mainwindow class like this (similar, might contain errors, but the principle should work):

```
QPixmap canvas(rect())

canvas.fill(Qt.transparent) # fill transparent (makes alpha channel available)

QPainter p(canvas)           # draw on the canvas
p.setOpacity(0.3)
p.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white)) # use the color you like
p.setPen(QPen(Qt.transparen))

p.drawRect(rect()) # draws the canvas with desired opacity

p.start(self)      # now draw on the window itself
p.drawPixmap(rect(), canvas)
```

Comment: What happens is that the button is still semi-transparent, and the background gets set a system defined color (instead of black, it's now whiteish). I'm not sure setWindowOpacity works on non-window widgets.

Comment: Edited my answer. I did it like this sometimes and it always worked as you need it.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to convert this QT pseudocode to PyQT and see how this works out.

Comment: I updated the original question. I converted the code to PyQt, however, it seems as though nothing is being painted. (see the update)

Comment: Oh, it seems it works if I set some dimensions for the QRect()! Now only to detect the screen size.

Comment: Ok, I'm from C++ .. my `rect()` means for you `self.rect()`, please accept the answer if it works for you. Sorry, quite a while since using PyQt for me ..

Comment: not a problem, the pseudocode helped me to get it working. I replaced the manual size detection with self.rect(). Thanks.

Comment: actually in your "solution" part above you never paint 'ON' the canvas. If you compare to my pseudo code were the painter paints first to the canvas and then transfers the canvas to self. but for you it seems sufficient to draw on self (´painter = QPainter(self)´). so it seems you can remove first and last line of your paint event. (for me that never worked directly on self/(this in c++). but very good if it does for you).

Comment: Correct obserivation. I had to remove the painter.start call, as this interface is not available in PyQt5. Also I created the painter directly on the window widget. I corrected the solution to remove the dead code.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to provide another solution in case someone else runs into this problem. The way I solved it is like this.

First set your background to be completely transparent. This only applies to the window's background, and not the children objects.

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

You can remove the border if you want with this.

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Now, if you want there to still be some background color, apply a QFrame to your window, and place all child objects within it. Using your style sheet, set the color of the frame and your desired opacity like this. The last value is the opacity percentage.

```
self.main_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 120, 185, 60)")
```